# Is there an equivalent of parseInt() in Google Closure?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I want to use every good thing that is provided in Google Closure Library. Some of them are not that convenient. For example the goog.date.Date is not well compatible to JavaScript's natural Date().

I wonder if there is something like parseInt() that parses a string into number. I checked [goog.math](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.math.html) but cannot find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.string.html#parseInt